# Get_feature and Get_feature_by_id problem

Tags: qgis, point, geometry-generator

Why does the function works with get_feature_by_id and doesn't with get_feature?

```
closest_point (
    geometry (get_feature (@layer, "num_plgnal" ,  '1')), 
    geometry (get_feature (@layer,  "num_plgnal" , '3'))
)
```

Result with get_feature, the point is not drawn:
[image]

```
closest_point (
    geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, '1')), 
    geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, '3'))
)
```

Result with get_feature_by_id:
[image]

Comment: Did you try with integer e.g `get_feature (@layer, "num_plgnal" ,  1)` to be sure your issue is not related to casting as `num_signal` is a number according to your screenshot?

Comment: Did you also changed `get_feature (@layer, "num_plgnal" ,  '1')` to `get_feature (@layer, 'num_plgnal' ,  '1')` or `get_feature (@layer, 'num_plgnal' ,  1)`? It's because doc example uses single quotes for column name https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=expressions#get-feature

Comment: it worked! That was the problem! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to change double quotes to single quotes for column name as seen in the expression documentation for `get_feature` https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=expressions#get-feature

Instead of

```
closest_point (
    geometry (get_feature (@layer, "num_plgnal" ,  '1')), 
    geometry (get_feature (@layer,  "num_plgnal" , '3'))
)
```

It should be

```
closest_point (
    geometry (get_feature (@layer, 'num_plgnal' ,  '1')), 
    geometry (get_feature (@layer,  'num_plgnal' , '3'))
)
```